Controls in FlowLayoutPanel Flickering When Scrolling (Even with Double Buffering) C#
I'm working on a WinForms application with a FlowLayoutPanel that contains multiple custom controls. When I scroll through, the controls noticeably flicker, even though I’ve enabled double buffering. My goal is to achieve a smooth scrolling experience without the visible flicker.
CUSTOM FLOWLAYOUTPANEL WITH BUFFERED
internal class DrawFLP : FlowLayoutPanel
    {
        public DrawFLP()
        {
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            //SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, 
true);
       }


        protected override void OnScroll(ScrollEventArgs se)
       {
            this.Invalidate();
            base.OnScroll(se);
        }
    }

POPULATING THE CUSTOM FLOWLAYOUT WITH CONTROLS
    private async void BtnSearchItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Enable double buffering on FLOWITEM
    SetDoubleBuffer(FLOWITEM, true);
    // Clear existing items and configure FLOWITEM properties
    FLOWITEM.Controls.Clear();
    FLOWITEM.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown;
    FLOWITEM.AutoScroll = true;

    // Populate the item list asynchronously
    for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1);
        var item = new Uis.CONTROLS.Item();
        FLOWITEM.Controls.Add(item);
    }
}

// Method to set double buffering on a control
static void SetDoubleBuffer(Control ctl, bool DoubleBuffer)
{
    try
    {
        typeof(Control).InvokeMember(
            "DoubleBuffered",
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance |
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty,
            null,
            ctl,
            new object[] { DoubleBuffer }
        );
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

What other techniques can I try to reduce or eliminate the flickering when scrolling through controls in a FlowLayoutPanel? Are there alternative methods or best practices for smooth scrolling in this scenario?
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Post only code parts that can reproduce the issue, remove the rest and the clutter. Post a sample of the Custom Control you're using, especially sections that use graphic objects or the Graphics class to draw stuff. After that, remove this: FLOWITEM.Controls.Clear();, possibly don't use it anymore (unless you know that it's safe to call this method. Not here)

But it code I post is simple enough for anyone to understand:
DrawFLP  is the usercontrol of FlowLayoutPanel
Main_Page where I called the buffered
BtnSearchItem_Click how I populate items into the DrawFLP
what else do you want me to explain?

Part of the code is commented out. Remove all that and post only the code that could reproduce the issue (possibly, correctly formatted). To actually reproduce the issue, you also need to post the Custom Control that you're adding to the FLP, because it's most probably what's causing the tearing you see there. Double-buffering the FLP (which might be needed or not, and in this case only once) could help in some causes. Not when the child Control are badly coded, and take a lot of time repainting themselves

Thanks, I have re-edit the the post kindly recheck and help me out
